# Can we use core php in codeigniter?

Tags: php, codeigniter

Can we use core php in codeigniter?

I would like to use core php code in codeigniter controller, if we use so please give me any reference.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: It's all just PHP, so yes, you can use any PHP class / function / language construct with codeigniter.

Comment: Codeigniter is just a MVC framework ,which provides you with MVC structure , inside the controllers and libraries you use the core php with little bit of built in codeigniter methods. As it's built on php , so yes you can use core php in any function and any controller. depends on you , how you want to use it

Comment: I have built a event calendar in core php, now i want to use it in codeigniter.

Comment: How to get your already existing code to be used in the context of codeigniter is a different question to what you've asked and depends on what you've built. In this case I would expect @raghbendra-nayak's answer to be of relevance.

Answer (score 1):

Codeigniter is simply PHP, so naturally you're able to run PHP as much as you wish, wherever you wish. Ideally you should do code like this in the controllers though to avoid breaking MVC (Model-View-Controller) patterns.

The only thing Codeigniter adds is a framework of PHP functions which "standardises" certain ways of doing things and provides a interface (or an API so to speak) to use these functions.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can use core PHP in the code igniter with the help of Helper classes. Just create a helper class and create a core PHP function into that helper class, where you want to use that function just load the helper and call that function directly.

Comment: Why would you need  helper class to run PHP functions? O_o

Comment: I am talking about the custom helper so in custom helper class you can directly include your PHP code  in a function body and then can call directly via function name where needed.

Comment: That works if you've got existing code (which OP has now said they do and I pointed out in comments this answer to be of relevance because of that), but what I took from your answer is that OP should create a helper even if they just wanted to use e.g. strpos, which obviously isn't really required.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can use core php as you wish.but it is risky if you amulgamate it with CI code.So if you want to use core php then you don't need to want help of Ci.